# CSS not loading on server but working fine on localhost when using ComponentFactory in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I am using ComponentFactory to open a new window which loads CSS on localhost

[image]

But when I deploy it on server, I does not load any CSS or bootstrap :

[image: server]

I'm using this code to open a window :

```
 documentList: any;
 OpenWindow: any;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef) { }

    viewDocument(docType) {
        this.openDocumentWindow(DocumentDetailsComponent, 'documentList', docType)
      }
    
      openDocumentWindow(component, list, data) {
        const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        let componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
        this.appRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
        this.OpenWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=900, height=600, left=200, top=100');
        this.OpenWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "";
        document.querySelectorAll('link, style').forEach(htmlElement => {
          this.OpenWindow.document.head.appendChild(htmlElement.cloneNode(true));
        });
        this.OpenWindow.document.body.appendChild(componentRef.location.nativeElement);
        componentRef.instance[list] = [data];
      }
```

Comment: Try clearing the cache and do a hard reload?

Comment: I did, it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i'm not particularly familiar with Angular or ComponentFactory, but i did have that exact issue with react and semantic react, where it'd work fine on local host on both dev and prod builds but omitted similar issue to you on deploying, after quite a bit of hit and try i fixed it by **importing the css using the CDN provided by semantic directly**, thou bootstrap parts were working fine without importing classes over the CDN.

I might be wrong but might wanna check if it is something similar to my issue.

Best of luck